# Get value from hash with indexers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a hash like

```
hash = {"19206"=>{"ordet_id"=>"4", "discount"=>"22"}, "19207"=>{"ordet_id"=>"2", "discount"=>"11"}}
```

There could me a lot indexers. What would be the best way get the `discount`value?

Something like this?

```
hash.each {|index, value| value[:discount]}
```

Or there is a better way how to proceed it?

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 2.3.4

Comment: Can you add your expected outcome?

Comment: Do you really run a version of Ruby on Rails that is more than 10 years old?

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7??? That was in use when dinosaurs roamed the planet.

Answer (score 2):

The keys in your nested hash are strings, therefore you cannot get the values by using a symbolized key. I would do something like this instead

```
hash.map { |_k, v| v['discount'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another version to get the expected result.

```
hash = hash.with_indifferent_access
discounts = hash.values.map(&:discount)
```